Add, delete, and modify data for the TortoiseORM model class in Cellery
The entire code logic is to save the data passed through the post request to the database. The Order model class is defined by Tortoise ORM, and when I save data in Cell, I always prompt "never await". The version of Cell is 5.3.6. I would like to ask how to use Tortoise ORM in Cell. Is it because both are asynchronous and incompatible? But didn't Celery 5 already support asynchrony from the beginning? Could you please help me check where my problem lies? Thank you very much. This issue has been bothering me for several days now
database.py
from tortoise.contrib.fastapi import register_tortoise
from fastapi import FastAPI
from etc.settings import settings

TORTOISE_ORM={
    "connections":{
        "default":{
            "engine":"tortoise.backends.mysql",
            "credentials":{
                "host":127.0.0.1,
                "port":"3306",
                "user":"username",
                "password":"password",
                "database":"test",
                "minsize":1,
                "maxsize":15,
                "charset":"utf8mb4",
                "echo":True
            }
        },
     
    },
    "apps":{
        "models":{
            "models":["aerich.models",
                      "models.details",
                      ],
            "default_connections":"default"
        },
    "use_tz":False,
    "timezone":"Asia/Shanghai",
}

async def register_mysql(app: FastAPI):
    # 注册数据库
    register_tortoise(
        app,
        config=TORTOISE_ORM,
    )

core.Events.py
from fastapi import FastAPI
from typing import Callable
from database import register_mysql

# from core.Topic import create_topic

def startup(app: FastAPI) -> Callable:
    """
    FastApi 启动完成事件
    :param app: FastAPI
    :return: start_app
    """

    async def app_start() -> None:
        # APP启动完成后触发
        print("fastapi已启动")
        # 注册数据库
        await register_mysql(app)
        print("数据库注册成功")
    return app_start

def stopping(app: FastAPI) -> Callable:
    """
    FastApi 停止事件
    :param app: FastAPI
    :return: stop_app
    """
    async def stop_app() -> None:
        # APP停止时触发
        print("fastapi已停止")

    return stop_app

main.py
from fastapi import FastAPI
import uvicorn
from fastapi.middleware.cors import CORSMiddleware
from core import Router,Events,Middleware
from etc.settings import settings

application = FastAPI()


# 路由
application.include_router(Router.router)

# 事件监听
application.add_event_handler("startup", Events.startup(application))

application.add_middleware(
    CORSMiddleware,
    allow_origins=settings.CORS_ORIGINS,
    allow_credentials=settings.CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS,
    allow_methods=settings.CORS_ALLOW_METHODS,
    allow_headers=settings.CORS_ALLOW_HEADERS,
)
app=application


if __name__ == '__main__':
    uvicorn.run("main:app",port=8090,reload=True,
                workers=1)

task_manager.__init.py
from celery import Celery

app=Celery("task_manager")                  #创建Celery_APP
app.config_from_object("task_manager.config")  #加载配置文件
#加载任务模块
app.autodiscover_tasks()

task_manager.config.py

from task_manager import app
from etc.settings import settings


broker_url=settings.CELERY_BROKER_URL
result_backend=None
broker_connection_retry_on_startup = True
accept_content = ['json'] 
task_serializer = 'json'
result_serializer=  "json" 
result_expires=60  
timezone="Asia/Shanghai" 
task_default_queue = 'delivery_queue'
task_default_exchange = 'delivery_exchange'

imports=(
    "task_manager.tasks",
)

task_manager.tasks.py

from task_manager import app
from models import Orders
def confirm_order_distribute(data):
    Orders.create(**data)

Router.py

from fastapi import APIRouter
from urllib.parse import unquote_plus
from task_manager.task import confirm_order_distribute


router = APIRouter(prefix='/delivery')

@router.post("/delivery",summary="数据处理")
async def data_view(request:Request):
    content_type = request.headers.get("content-type", "")
    if "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" in content_type:
        form_data = await request.form()
        decoded_form_data = {key: unquote_plus(value) for key, value in form_data.items()}
        if decoded_form_data :
            confirm_order_distribute.delay(decoded_form_data)
    return {"data":"ok"}

models.PY
from tortoise import fields,Model
class Orders(Model):
    id=fields.CharField(max_length=32,pk=True,unique=True,description="Id")
   latitude=fields.FloatField(null=True,description="纬度")
   longitude=fields.FloatField(null=True,description="经度")
   .......

